# Is it possible to put a Google Maps V2 MapFragment inside an ActionBar tab?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, android-actionbar, google-maps-android-api-2

I have an application which uses action bar tabs. I am trying to upgrade the application to use Google Maps V2 (MapFragment) but when the MapFragment is passed into the fragment container from the main activity, it all crashes.

MapFragment:

```
public class EstablishmentGoogleMapFragment extends MapFragment {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View root = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        mMap = getMap();
        return root;
    }
}
```

Fragment Transaction:

```
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        if(fragment == null){
            String fragmentName = fragmentClass.getName();
            fragment = Fragment.instantiate(activity, fragmentName);
            ft.add(fragmentContainer, fragment, fragmentName);
        } else {
            ft.attach(fragment);
        }
    }
```

LogCat:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.rb.hellojson/com.rb.hellojson.EstablishmentGoogleMapFragment}:
      java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rb.hellojson.EstablishmentGoogleMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2024)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rb.hellojson.EstablishmentGoogleMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity
    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1057)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2015)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: What is the crash (logcat)? Where is your code?

Comment: I have updated the question body

Comment: Can you add Manifest file?

Comment: Manifest should be fine since the code worked well with the Google example, displaying a map in just an activity. Still want it?

Comment: I think so. Something is starting your fragment like it was an activity. And if it's not Launcher, because fragment is defined in Manifest...

Comment: You sir are a genius! I had forgot to change the default activity back after testing the Google tutorial with a Map Activity. Silly mistake on my part, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error should be clear:

`Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: com.rb.hellojson.EstablishmentGoogleMapFragment cannot be cast to android.app.Activity`

Are you trying to do startActivity on this fragment or what?

For later fixes: `mMap = getMap();` will return null at this point (or maybe not).

Edit:

Something is starting your fragment like it was an activity. And if it's not Launcher, because fragment is defined in Manifest...

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. No, it is part of a Fragment Transaction. I'll update the question body to show.

Comment: getMap() doesn't return null here, but you were right in that the fragment was trying to be started as an activity by the manifest. Please can you edit and I'll approve the answer.